# Filled contour polygons from Terrain50 polyline contours

Tags: arcgis-desktop, ordnance-survey

I am trying to create filled polygons from the Ordnance Surveys Terrain 50 contour polylines.

I have tried the simple Feature to Polygon tool in ArcGIS 10.4, but this does not bring across the height attributes.

Is there a simple way to quickly create filled polygons? I would like to ideally do it across a large section of the UK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you have converted the lines to polygons with Feature to Polygon, you can use Spatial Join to join the attributes of the lines to the matching polygons. Set the polygons as Target Features, the lines as Join Features and make sure you use "BOUNDARY_TOUCHES" as match option:

[image]